# How to prove if two objects collide using relativistic equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, collision

Suppose you see two objects moving in space towards each other, you also see them colliding now can you prove that mathmatically using Lorentz transformations or anything else. **But only under relativity**

Comment: I am not quite good in English so please excuse me if any grammatical mistakes

Answer (score 1):

A collision is a physical event; it happens independently of what frame you use or boost to via Lorentz transform. It either happens, or it doesn't.

You specify the initial conditions-velocity and positions-in some frame, and if they allow collision (i.e. if there exists a $t$ in *that* frame where their positions coincide-see the answer by @CharlesFrancis), then you can carry out transformations as you please, and they will still collide.

In this sense, there is nothing special relativistic about predicting collisions-it amounts to choosing the right initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In special relativity you can describe the 4-position of an object as a vector $(t,x,y,z)$. To avoid having too many letters, we usually write that $x = (x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, so $x^0$ is time and the other components are position. Then two objects with 4-positions $x$ and $y$ collide when $x=y$. Because the description uses 4-vectors, it is unchanged by Lorentz transformation.